# Hosting discord bot through Heroku - deploy error

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to host my discord bot through heroku. I'm coding with python. But I got the following error when deploying from GitHub:

```
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.6
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.9.6
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite (from -r /tmp/build_25682582/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to /tmp/pip-req-build-hv03qzyg
         WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

That was the full build log that I saw on heroku.
Can anyone help? Thx

Comment: Every time I try to deploy it I get the same error. Also tried switching to use Heroku CLI method in command line but same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the first line in `requirements.txt` to `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`. Because there is no tag or branch named "rewrite".